# Unit Test Azure Cloud Services

Tags: unit-testing, azure

I wrote a couple of visual studio unit tests to test business logic included in worker role.

My worker role publishes message to Azure topics. For this I have specified connection strings in CloudConfig.cfg & I pick up the settings using `RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue()`. Since tests run in their own app domain & not inside azure emulator. Call to those functions would obviously fail.

What are the best practices out there to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue`, use [`CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.getsetting.aspx). This will pick up configuration settings from appropriate config file - service configuration file if your code is running in context of a cloud service or app.config/web.config otherwise.